# Accessing variables in the local scope of a python decorator

Tags: python, scope, closures, local

Consider:

```
def g(value):
    def f():
        return value
    return f

x = g(3)
x() # prints 3
```

Given `x` in the example, the returned closure from `g(3)`, is there any way to inspect that is the value of `value` without calling `x()`?

Comment: There is a typo in the example, you forgot to `return f` in `g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can directly introspect the closure for a function in Python:

```
>>> def g(value):
...     def f():
...         return value
...     return f
...
>>> func = g(42)
>>> func.__closure__
(<cell at 0x1077b5a80: int object at 0x1075b4618>,)
```

Then if you want the value:

```
>>> cell =  func.__closure__[0]
>>> cell.cell_contents
42
```